# How liferay writes default.xml on ResourcePermission table?

Tags: java, database, permissions, liferay

I would like to know how Liferay writes the `ResourcePermission` table after reading the (usually named) *default.xml* file defined in the *portlet.properties* file as `resource.actions.configs=resource-actions/default.xml`

I'm looking for it in the documentation, there are some posts about how the permission system work: [Deep dive in Roles and Permissions](https://web.liferay.com/web/mohit.soni/blog/-/blogs/deep-dive-in-roles-and-permissions) and [Liferay Permission System Detailed Concept](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/liferay-permission-system-detailed.html)

But I founded nothing about how service builder writes permission on database, and I have a problem because my portlet is writing in the `ResourcePermission` table those permissions related to the portlet itself and to the model parent class (i.e. `com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model`), but it is not writing those permissions related to the model specific classes (i.e. `com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Guestbook`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: You should not look at the database - never. It's a recipe for disaster as soon as you try to change any value in there.

As of the individual object's permissions, they're not persisted once default.xml is read. Instead they get stored when a model object is created - they are valid (and changeable) for each individual object, thus there's not a single record. It's rather (at least) one per object. And in the beginning you have zero objects, thus zero records.

But, let me repeat: If you can't describe a Liferay problem by a description to reproduce on the UI: Don't go there. Never - NEVER - change the database manually. Do yourself that favour.

Comment: Ok, thanks Olaf. So I understand that for individual objects permissions are not persistent. I will post another question with my problem, because with PermissionChecker.hasPermission(...) it is not returning the defined value for ´<site-member-defaults>´ and ´<guest-defaults>´

Comment: Well, individual object's permissions are persisted, but only with those objects. In your own implementation you typically use ResourceLocalService for this.

Comment: I don't understand very well. So if individual object's permissions are persisted they should appear in the ResourcePermission table, shouldn't they? I mean, I think my problem is because default.xml is not saving permissions for com.liferay.docs.guestbook.model.Guestbook.

Comment: You don't write about your problem at all. All you did was asking where data is written to the database. Describe your observations (without referencing the database content) and expected behaviour.